# Backup suddenly is taking too long to complete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, backup

We have an SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition database around 3 TB in size. We are taking compressed full backup weekly, it was working fine till last week and now suddenly it is taking 18 hours to complete.

When backup completes the backup size is around 550 GB.

Backup drive has around 950 GB disk space free.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is it possible the service account was changed, or removed from administrators group, or group policy changed to no longer support IFI? [See here for some other ideas on gathering your own diagnostics](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-66-babysitting-a-slow-backup-or-restore/).

Comment: None of this has been changed

Comment: How long was the full backup taking before? Did it go from 12hrs to 18hrs? Or from 1hr to 18hrs?

Comment: Is the backup drive a local drive, or on shared network storage?

Comment: It is local drive

Comment: Back up go from 12hr to 18hr

Comment: How we can reduce the time taken by backup any script or configuration need to be changed .

Comment: Hi All, I got a work around in place to fix this as to use Buffer size, Block size and max transfer size. Please find the reference for the same 

http://henkvandervalk.com/how-to-increase-sql-database-full-backup-speed-using-compression-and-solid-state-disks

Answer (score 12):

There's basically 4 things involved with backup speed:

1. Reading from the data files - you can test this by doing a backup to NUL:, as in this example, which won't break your log-backup chain for full recovery model databases:

   ```
   BACKUP DATABASE xyz TO DISK = 'NUL:' WITH COPY_ONLY;
   ```
2. Compressing the data - watch CPU pressure during the backup.
3. Getting it through the network path to its final location (optional, only for network backups) - test this with a network file copy.
4. Writing it to the disk on its final target location - test this with something like CrystalDiskMark or DiskSpd, but has to be done locally (not over a network pipe, since you want to avoid #3 affecting your results).

Third party backup products like Quest LiteSpeed, Idera SQLsafe, and Red Gate SQL Backup (disclaimer: I'm independent, but I've worked with all of those companies in the past) have wizards that will test each component of that, and then tell you where the bottleneck is. If you want to find it yourself, you're going to have to test each of those components, and then find the weakest link in the chain (the lowest throughput).

For example, if other SQL Servers are writing to the same target location, they may have suddenly had an increase of data or added more servers, thereby slowing down the target.

Comment: there's also some fun XML shredding to be done with the `databases_backup_restore_throughput` XE. at one point i'd even figured out how to isolate events by backup stripe. it turned my brain to goo, though.

Comment: Can't there also be locking issues that would cause the backups to pause while waiting for a lock to release?

Comment: Not a lock inside the database, but there can be locks on the msdb backup history tables (although that's fairly unusual.)

Comment: @BrentOzar - I hope you don't mind my edit.  Also, I'm starting to think you're trolling me with the disclaimers  ;-)

Comment: @MaxVernon well, I wouldn't want to break the rules. ;-)

Comment: Hi All, I got a work around in place to fix this as to use Buffer size, Block size and max transfer size.  Please find the reference for the same                     http://henkvandervalk.com/how-to-increase-sql-database-full-backup-speed-using-compression-and-solid-state-disks